# Windows Batch file to decrypt ransomware

Tags: batch-file, encryption

Im searching for a batch file or another solution to decrypt thousonds of files in different folders (Each single file is encrypted in a .7z file)
The password is known. But how is it possible to unpack all files without loosing the folder structure?
Can someone help me with this? I found one batch file with the help of google:

```
SET source=I:\Multimedia
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.7z"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -p1234567890 "%%~fF" -o"%%~pF\"
EXIT
```

But it seems that this code is unpacking the files of the external HDD(I:) to the internal HDD(C:)
Is it possible to modify the code? So that it unpack the files in the same folder and maybe delete the .7z file after unpacking?

Regards

Comment: To begin with, as you're using `Dir` with `/S` and `I:\Multimedia`, `%%F` will already be the full and absolute path. That means, `"%%~fF"` should be `"%%F"`. Next `"%%~pF\"` will be the full path but without the drive letter,`I:` _(and as `~p` always includes a trailing backwards slash it will now end with two of them)_, so the extraction will occur in the drive relative to the current directory. I would assume that your current directory is located on the `C:` drive, so perhaps therefore, you should change `"%%~pF\"` to `"%%~dpF"`. To delete the archive, check the `ErrorLevel` is `Not` `1`.